# Django User with is_active=False login via GoogleOAuth2

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, django-socialauth

I have a Django app with login via GoogleOAuth2:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
     ...
)
```

When I try to login as a user with `User.is_active=True` (`django.contrib.auth.models.User`), it's all OK.

But when I try to login as a user with `User.is_active=False`, I got nothing. No error, just login page again.

What can be an issue? 
How I should handle this error?

Comment: share some code with us please

Comment: @py_dude but there are almost no code... `social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2` does all stuff for me. But it does not work correctly with `User.is_active=False`.

Comment: Do you want to let inactive users login or do you want them to be shown an error page that tells them to reactivate their account?

Comment: @saad I want to show them an error.

Comment: RIght. And can your users who use your django based username and password authentication login if their accounts are disabled?

Comment: @saad they cannot. But they get an error message from `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`. I want them to get a similar error message when they try to login via google account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for python-social-auth:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_INACTIVE_USER_URL = '/inactive-user/'
```

> Inactive users can be redirected to this URL when trying to authenticate.

You can set this link to a page for inactive users in your settings. Here's the [link](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/settings.html) to the docs

Comment: Thank you @saad!! You Haley me a lot! Also, you need to set SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User' variable to get access to User.is_active.

Comment: There is also an entire [pipeline](https://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html) of functions that you can customize.